# Changing a variable reference in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am having a hard time figuring out how to reassign a variable to a new function.

I have two anonymous functions that are assigned to variables and I want "first" to assign itself to "after" after it is called once.

When using `.toSource` in Firefox it seems like it is definitely reassigning first to after, but the "first in the click handler is still referencing or calling the first that was created at runtime.

Why is this?

JS

```
var after = function() {
    alert("AFTER");
}

var first = function() {
    alert("FIRST");
    //alert(first.toSource());
    first = after;
}

$(".order").click( first );
```

HTML

```
<button type="button" class="order">Order</button>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/E2R2R/2/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following up on @MichaelGeary s answer, if you want to make the function work by referencing like that, put your function call inside an anonymous function:

```
$(".order").click( function() {
    first();    
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/E2R2R/4/

Comment: I can't believe it is that easy. I don't know why I couldn't think of this.

Answer (score 5):

When you make this call:

```
$(".order").click( first );
```

you are using the value of `first` *at the time of this call*. Its value at that time is what is passed into the `click()` function.

Changing the value of the `first` variable later won't affect this.

Another way to look at it: think about the code inside jQuery's `click()` method. It doesn't know that you used the `first` variable in your call. The only information it has is the function that `first` refers to at the time of the call.

See @tymeJV's answer for a way to do what you want. Note what's different about it: the function you're passing into `.click()` (the anonymous function) doesn't have to change. When that function calls `first()`, it always uses the *current* value of that name.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. I appreciate your help. I always like understanding the why.